# How to transmit data from a sensor using SIM800L?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using soil sensor with Arduino UNO. I wish to transmit data coming from sensor to a server using sim800l.
I am unable to find any help on this. please guide me.

Comment: which part of the project are you able to do now?

Comment: I read about basic interfacing like send and read SMS and calling methods.I am able to read the data from sensor but I am unable to find a code/ function to upload it.

Comment: try this... https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/GSM_SIM800L_Sheild_with_Arduino